# My program which creates a abbreviation of an char array, does not print anything. Where is my mistake?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am supposed to create a program, which creates an array with the abbreviation of an constant char Array. While my program does not return any errors, it also does not print any characters at my certain printf spots. Because of that I assume that my program does not work properly, and it isn't filling my array with any characters.

```
void abbrev(const char s[], char a[], size_t size) {
    int i = 0;
    while (*s != '\0') {
        printf('%c', *s);
        if (*s != ' ' && *s - 1 == ' ') {
            a[i] = *s;
            i++;
            printf('%c', a[i]);
        }
        s++;
    }
}


void main() {
    char jordan1[60] = "  Electronic      Frontier  Foundation ";
    char a[5];
    size_t size = 5;
    abbrev(jordan1, a, size);
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

The actual result is nothing. At least I assume so, since my console isn't showing anything. The result should be "EFF" and the size_t size is supposed to limit my char array a, in case the abbreviation is too long. So it should only implement the letters until my array is full and then the '\0', but I did not implement it yet, since my program is apparantly not filling the array at all.

Comment: Run your debugger and step through the code to see where it goes. Examine the contents of the variables and you will see what is happening.

Comment: `if (*s != ' ' && *s - 1 == ' ') {` <<-- will never be true.  (well, for a `!`)

Comment: As @wildplasser wrote, the dereference happens before the subtraction. You need some parens.

Comment: Add `puts("");` before you return from `abbrev()` to force a flush of the standard output stream (or do it explicitly: `fflush(stdout);`).

Comment: @wildplasser Thanks for your answer forgot the parens as nicomp pointed out.

Comment: Using a negative index is dangerous, at least. In your case you will addres the string **below** its first character.

Comment: The first mistake is lack of necessary `#include` directives.

Comment: While we might sometimes write `*s`, it is not good style to write `*(s - 1)` even with the correct parenthesization. Good style is `s[0]` and `s[-1]`.

Comment: Note that `s[-1]` is not valid if `s` points to the beginning of an array.

Comment: Also you should have gotten compile-time diagnostics for `'%c'` as the argument to `printf`, and for `void main`, neither of which are correct, yet I don't see any mention in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* in: the string to abbreviate
   out: output abbreviation. Function assumes there's enough room */
void abbrev(const char in[], char out[])
{
    const char *p; 
    int zbPosOut = 0;     /* current zero-based position within the `out` array */

    for (p = in; *p; ++p) { /* iterate through `in` until we see a zero terminator */

        /* if the letter is uppercase
              OR if (the letter is alphabetic AND we are not at the zero 
              position AND the previous char. is a space character) OR if the
              letter is lowercase and it is the first char. of the array... */
        if (isupper(*p) || (isalpha(*p) && (p - in) > 0 && isspace(p[-1])) 
                        || (islower(*p) && p == in)) {

            out[zbPosOut++] = *p; /* ... then the letter is the start letter
                          of a word, so add it to our `out` array, and 
                          increment the current `zbPosOut` */
        }
    }
    out[zbPosOut] = 0; /* null-terminate the out array */
}
```

This code says a lot in few lines. Let's take a look:

```
isupper(*p) || (isalpha(*p) && (p - in) > 0 && isspace(p[-1])) 
           || (islower(*p) && p == in)
```

If the current character (`*p`) is an uppercase character OR if it is alphabetc (`isalpha(*p)` and the previous character `p[-1]` is a space, then we may consider `*p` to be the first character of a word, and it should be added to our `out` array. We include the test `(p - in) > 0` because if `p == in`, then we are at the zero position of the array and therefore `p[-1]` is undefined.

The order in this expression matters a lot. If we were to put `(p - in) > 0` *after* the `isspace(p[-1])` test, then we would not be taking advantage of the laziness of the `&&` operator: as soon as it encounters a false operand, the following operand is not evaluated. This is important because if `p - in == 0`, then we do not want to evaluate the `isspace(p[-1])` expression. The order in which we have written the tests makes sure that `isspace(p[-1])` is evaluated after making sure we are not at the zero position.

The final expression `(islower(*p) && p == in)` handles the case where the first letter is lowercase.

```
out[zbPosOut++] = *p;
```

We append the character `*p` to the `out` array. The current position of `out` is kept track of by the `zbPosOut` variable, which is incremented afterwards (which is why we use postscript `++` rather than prefix).

Code to test the operation of `abbrev`:

```
int main()
{
    char jordan1[] = "  electronic      frontier  foundation ";
    char out[16];

    abbrev(jordan1, out);
    puts(out);

    return 0;
}
```

It gives `eff` as the output. For it to look like an acronym, we can change the code to append the letter `*p` to `out` to:

```
out[zbPosOut++] = toupper(*p);
```

which capitalizes each letter added to the `out` array (if `*p` is already uppercase, `toupper` just returns `*p`).

Answer (score 0):

```
void print_without_duplicate_leading_trailing_spaces(const char *str)
{
    while(*str == ' ' && *str) str++;
    while(*str)
    {
        if(*str != ' ' || (*str == ' ' && *(str + 1) != ' '  && *str))
        {
            putchar(*str);
        }
        str++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What you want to do could be simplified with a [`for()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/loops-in-c-and-cpp/) loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void abbrev(const char s[], char a[], size_t size) {
  int pos = 0;
  // Loop for every character in 's'.
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    // If the character just before was a space, and this character is not a
    // space, and we are still in the size bounds (we subtract 1 for the
    // terminator), then copy and append.
    if (s[i] != ' ' && s[i - 1] == ' ' && pos < size - 1)
      a[pos++] = s[i];
  printf("%s\n", a); // Print.
}

void main() {
  char jordan1[] = " Electronic    Frontier  Foundation ";
  char a[5];
  size_t size = 5;
  abbrev(jordan1, a, size);
}
```

However, I don't think this is the best way to achieve what you are trying to do. Firstly, `char s[0]` cannot be gotten due to the check on the previous character. Which brings me to the second reason: On the first index you will be checking `s[-1]` which probably isn't a good idea. If I were implementing this function I would do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void abbrev(const char s[], char a[], size_t size) {
  char *str = strdup(s); // Make local copy.
  size_t i = 0;
  // Break it up into words, then grab the first character of each word.
  for (char *w = strdup(strtok(str, " ")); w != NULL; w = strtok(NULL, " "))
    if (i < size - 1)
      a[i++] = w[0];
  free(str); // Release our local copy.
  printf("%s\n", a);
}

int main() {
  char jordan1[] = "Electronic    Frontier  Foundation ";
  char a[5];
  size_t size = 5;
  abbrev(jordan1, a, size);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: UB `if (s[i] != ' ' && s[i - 1] == ' ' && pos < size - 1)`